# How do I save an array of JSON encoded contents with the square bracket?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using Javascript and NodeJS to dynamically create an array of JSON objects. I want to save this array of JSON objects to a .json file for future use. However, when I save the file, I only get the contents separated by commas, but not the outer square brackets.

I use the fs.writeFile to do this. I have the dynamically created array with JSON objects, separated by commas. My function is shown below.

```
fs.writeFile('json_files/output_'+id+'.json', ret_vals, function (err) {
                    if (err) 
                        return console.log(err);
                    console.log('Success!');
                });
```

The file I get from the output looks like this:

{"x":"y"}, {"x":"z"}, {"x":"t"}

However, I want my .json file to look like this:
[{"x":"y"}, {"x":"z"}, {"x":"t"} ]

So basically, I want the array brackets to exist too. For reference, I create an array called ret_vals using let ret_vals = [], and then use .push() to add these jsons to it.

If I use stringify, I get the brackets, but the array contents are also surrounded by quotation marks, making it impossible to run any JSON comparator on the contents, since it just identifies that the whole sentence is different. How would I proceed to do what I want?

Comment: use `JSON.stringify` to create JSON

Comment: Like @JaromandaX said, use JSON.stringify to write it  and then JSON.parse when you need to interact with it.

Comment: Basically, I'm calling an API that returns a JSON object, then I push that to my array.

Comment: AS @JaromandaX says, please use `JSON.stringify`, you can take a look this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883743/how-can-i-write-an-array-to-a-file-in-nodejs-and-keep-the-square-brackets/46167406.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I write an array to a file in nodejs and keep the square brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883743/how-can-i-write-an-array-to-a-file-in-nodejs-and-keep-the-square-brackets)

Answer (score 1):

Yes `json.stringify` will work for your question and when you need to work on it use`json parse` to convert the stringified object to array object